# Rufus-scheduler not working on nginx/passenger in environment production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, passenger, rufus-scheduler

I’m having problems with rufus-scheduler not working in environment production, i’m tried adding: 
`passenger_spawn_method direct;
passenger_min_instances 1;
rails_app_spawner_idle_time 0;`
 
in the nginx config but it would still not solve the problem.

my code using rufus-scheduler:

```
    def expired_at=(datetime)
    datetime = Time.zone.parse(datetime) if datetime.class == String && !datetime.empty?
    if expired_at
      expired_at
    else
      if datetime > Time.zone.now
        scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
        begin
          scheduler.at datetime.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M") do
            self.update_attributes(:finished => true )
          end
        rescue => ex
          Rails.logger.info ex.message
          Rails.logger.info ex.backtrace
        end
      else
        self[:finished] = true
      end
      self[:expired_at] = datetime
    end
  end
```

I'm stuck in this problem. Your help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

I'm using:

- nginx: 1.8.0
- fusion passenger: 5.0.10
- rufus-scheduler: 3.1.3

Comment: Could you please define what "I'm having problems" means? Are you trying to cook eggs with it and they stay cold? http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: sr i don't know problems,i just think nginx passenger preventing rufus scheduler. :(

Answer (score 0):

I cannot solve your problem, because you're not describing what actually happens (or doesn't happen).

But, I can tell you that your code is poorly thought.

Your `expired_at=` method, I guess it's a model method. So, do you realize that you are initializing a rufus-scheduler instance each time you are calling `expired_at=`?

you'd better try

```
def expired_at=(datetime)

  datetime = Time.zone.parse(datetime) \
    if datetime.class == String && !datetime.empty?

  if expired_at
    expired_at
  else
    if datetime > Time.zone.now
      begin
        Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.at datetime.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M") do
          self.update_attributes(:finished => true )
        end
      rescue => ex
        Rails.logger.info ex.message
        Rails.logger.info ex.backtrace
      end
    else
      self[:finished] = true
    end
    self[:expired_at] = datetime
  end
end
```

It relies on `Rufus::Scheduler.singleton` so you'll use a single rufus-scheduler instance. Another alternative would be to start the scheduler in an initializer and then leverage it from your model. Perhaps you'll be forced to do just that since Passenger probably won't keep a thread created by an incoming request around. You'll have to carefully test (and thus learn).

**But**, you could also change your way of thinking and have a single rufus-scheduler job that wakes up, say twice a day, and queries for models with an expired_at value and set finished to true if necessary. If you go that way, you could use [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever): wrap your query+update in a Rake task and let Whenever (in fact your system's crond) call it twice a day for you (advantage: you don't have to tweak your Passenger settings).

Good luck!